# Как отобразить анимированную 3d модель .dae (COLLADA) используя OPENGL?

Tags: ios, opengl

Как отобразить анимированную 3d модель .dae (COLLADA) используя OPENGL? Не используя Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено при помощи ScreenKit. Он отлично работает с .dae (COLLADA) форматом

https://developer.apple.com/scenekit/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit